# Linking together Repository pattern, caching and web-service

Tags: c#, web-services, design-patterns, caching, repository-pattern

I'm try to understand `Repository` pattern to implement it in my app. And I'm stuck with it in a some way.

Here is a simplified algorithm of how the app is accessing to a data:

1. At first time the app has no data. It needs to connect to a web-service to get this data. So all the low-level logic of interaction with the web-service will be hiding behind the `WebServiceRepository` class. All the data passed from the web-service to the app will be cached.
2. Next time when the app will request the data this data will be searched in the cache before requesting them from the web-service. Cache represents itself as a database and XML files and will be accessed through the `CacheRepository`.

   The cached data can be in three states: valid (can be shown to user), invalid (old data that can't be shown) and partly-valid (can be shown but must be updated as soon as possible).

   a) If the cached data is valid then after we get them we can stop.

   b) If the chached data is invalid or partly-valid we need to access `WebServiceRepository`. If the access to the web-service is ended with a success then requested data will be cached and then will be showed to user (I think this must be implemented as a second call to the `CacheRepository`).

   c) So the entry point of the data access is the `CacheRepository`. Web-service will be called only if there is no fully valid cache.

I can't figure out where to place the logic of verifying the cache (valid/invalid/partly-valid)? Where to place the call of the `WebServiceRepository`? I think that this logic can't be placed in no one of `Repositories`, because of violation the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) from SOLID.

Should I implement some sort of `RepositoryService` and put all the logic in it? Or maybe is there a way to link `WebServiceRepository` and `WebServiceRepository`?

What are patterns and approaches to implement that?

Another question is how to get partly-valid data from cache and then request the web-service in the one method's call? I think to use delegates and events. Is there other approaches?

Please, give an advice. Which is the correct way to link all the functionality listed above?

P.S. Maybe I described all a bit confusing. I can give some additional clarifications if needed.

P.P.S. Under `CacheRepository` (and under `WebServiceRepository`) I meant a set of repositories - `CustomerCacheRepository`, `ProductCacheRepository` and so on. Thanks @hacktick for the comment.

Comment: Are you in control of the web service?  Is the cache a client-side cache or server-side cache?

Comment: @dtryon No, I'm not. I can only get data from web-service through XML API. The cache is client-side.

Comment: Why have a separate repository?  Just use a cache dependency in each entity repository.  Then you don't need to dynamically resolve the dependency.

Comment: @dtryon Because data requested from the server will be stored in database and files. I need to hide all low-level data access details. So repository pattern is suitable for this in my opinion.
What you mean under a cache dependency? Can you tell more about this?

Comment: I think me and @hacktick are speaking about the same thing: `IDataCache instance for every repository`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your webservice gives you crud methods for different entities create a repository for every entityroot.
if there are customers create a CustomerRepository. if there are documents with attachments as childs create a DocumentRepository that returns documents with attachments as a property.

a repository is only responsible for a specific type of entity (ie. customers or documents). repositories are not used for "cross cutting concerns" such as caching. (ie. your example of an CacheRepository)

inject (ie. StuctureMap) a IDataCache instance for every repository.

a call to Repository.GetAll() returns all entities for the current repository. every entity is registered in the cache. note the id of that object in the cache.

a call to Repository.FindById() checks the cache first for the id. if the object is valid return it.

notifications about invalidation of an object is routed to the cache. you could implement client-side invalidation or push messages from the server to the client for example via messagequeues.

information about the status whether an object is currently valid or not should not be stored in the entity object itself but rather only in the cache.

Comment: Under `CacheRepository` (and under `WebServiceRepository`) I meant a set of repositories - `CustomerCacheRepository`, `ProductCacheRepository` and so on. It's my mistake that I didn't written this in the question. And thanks for your answer.

Comment: So all data storage and validation logic moves to implementation of IDataCache. When repository needs to return entity objects it must to refer to the injected implementation of IDataCache and to figure out is there any valid data or not. If not not then it requests for data to web-service. Do I understand your answer in the correct way?

Comment: Can you answer me on my previous comment? Please.

Comment: No the IDataCache Instance is only responsible for caching. so it holds the objid of each entity and the entity and the "is valid" status. the repository is reponsible for acting properly according to the datacache. if for example a repository notices that one entity is invalid (according to the cache) it could reload that entity or just mark it properly so that it could be displayed to the user as for example outdated.